# Error con entorno virtual y MySQL en Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask, python-import

Estaba intentando hacer una práctica en Python, más concretamente en Flask en un entorno virtual, porque así es como me han enseñado a usar Flask.
El problema viene cuando intento importar la librería que uso para MySQL, para instalar la librería escribía: `pip install mysql-connector-python`, se instalaba, pero cuando escribo `import mysql.connector` me sale el siguiente error:

> Import "mysql.connector" could not be resolved

¿Cómo podría resolver este error?

Answer (score 0):

Vi esta respuesta en StackOverflow forum. Aun en proceso de validar.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022361/why-in-vscode-does-not-let-me-import-mysql

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al stackoverflow Español Cristian!, en la sección de respuesta debe haber respuestas concretas a la pregunta, cualquier sugerencia a revisar otro enlace se puede hacer mediante un comentario. También tienes la opción de replicar la solución que encontraste al español

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/374625)